# firestore how to pass doc.data() as an object return value in JavaScrip?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, javascript-objects, return-value

took func from google's firestore get documentation.

want to write a function which returns the document's data (as the object returns from db or dict), not just prints to consol.

i have a collection name users and i'm trying to get a user's data with it's key from db.

for some reason it doesn't pass the doc.data() when returns, print's undefined, although within the function prints the user's data (for sure data is defined in db). would love to know why.

Thank you!

```
var newData = getDocumentById("users","0c52f893-f0dc-4b68-a3cd-d4ffdb014375")
console.log("this is newData",newData);  // prints "this is newData undefined"

function getDocumentById(collectionType,docId){
var docRef = db.collection(collectionType).doc(docId);

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        dataExtracted = doc.data();

        console.log(dataExtracted); //  prints the doc's data to console just fine
        return dataExtracted;
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("func getDocumentById: collection type:",collectionType,", doc type:",docId,",No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful you are playing with promises. You have to use await or .then to wait for the result. Try the following:

```
var newData = await getDocumentById("users","0c52f893-f0dc-4b68-a3cd-d4ffdb014375")
console.log("this is newData",newData);  // prints "this is newData undefined"

async function getDocumentById(collectionType,docId){
  var docRef = db.collection(collectionType).doc(docId);

  return docRef.get()
  .then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        dataExtracted = doc.data();

        console.log(dataExtracted); //  prints the doc's data to console just fine
        return dataExtracted;
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("func getDocumentById: collection type:",collectionType,", doc type:",docId,",No such document!");
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you @Oliver! in console it printed a promise even through it was inside .then{}, didn't it supposed to return the object itself? can i return only a valid object once one exists?

Comment: You have to wait for the promise to resolve before you can use its output. Inside the then it should show the object, yes